# Touchpad stops working after a while

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and my touchpad works fine, but it stops working after a random period of time (sometimes hours, sometimes it doesn't). With "stops working" I mean that I cannot move the pointer, but I'm still able to left click. The touchpad works fine with Windows 10, but gave me the same problem with Linux Mint.
When this happens the touchpad is recognised in `xinput`
and enabled in the options, so I think that it might be a driver issue. Anyway I have no idea how to fix it even after reading several solution her in the forum; everytime it happens I have to `sudo reboot`  from the terminal and then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently all I had to do was set the Touchpad mode to "Basic" in the BIOS. The issue didn't happened again since.

Comment: I was getting frustrated but your solution saved me! thanks.